# JavaScript - EventListener doesn't work in external js file

Tags: javascript, html, inline, addeventlistener

When I put my javascript in a script tag in the footer of my html file everything works fine. But when I link to an external script file with the exact same code in it, my EventListener doesn't work. I also have other code in the same external script file that works just fine.
Any idea what could be my mistake?

The following lines work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="scroll-lottie" style="min-height: 500px; margin-top: 100px">Test</div>
<script>
  // scroll animations
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const scrollable = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
    const scrolled = window.scrollY;
    const scrolledPercentage = scrolled/scrollable*100;

    // scroll lottie disappear animation
    if(scrolledPercentage > 5){
        document.getElementById("scroll-lottie").style.opacity = "0";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("scroll-lottie").style.opacity = "1";
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I put the javascript in an external file, it doesn't:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
    container: document.getElementById('scroll-lottie'), // Required
    path: '../animations/scroll_down_animation.json', // Required
    renderer: 'svg', // Required
    loop: true, // Optional
    autoplay: true, // Optional
    name: "Scroll Down Animation", // Name for future reference. Optional.
  })

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const scrollable = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  const scrolled = window.scrollY;
  const scrolledPercentage = scrolled/scrollable*100;

  // scroll lottie disappear animation
  if(scrolledPercentage > 5){
      document.getElementById("scroll-lottie").style.opacity = "0";
  }
  else{
      document.getElementById("scroll-lottie").style.opacity = "1";
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="scroll-lottie" style="min-height: 500px; margin-top: 100px"></div>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your webpage doesn't have any height, scrolling doesn't happen so the event doesn't get triggered.
If you add this into your head then you can see that it is happening if you include a console.log into the scroll event

```html
  <style>
    #scroll-lottie{
      min-height: 200vh;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: My Page does have a hight. I just didn't include the contet here. But as I said it works fine when I put the javascript in the html file.

Comment: What is your file structure like? When I tested your code it worked fine

Comment: I already solved the problem but I still don't understand what the problem was. I can't include the full HTML because it is a private website but I now included the full javascript. So basically I had the js for two different html files in the same js file. Now I just took the part that wasn't working and put it in a seperate js file and it worked. So it has something to do with the javascript above the loadAnimation function. Do you know what it is?

Comment: Are you sure that the scroll event was even happening? From what you have shown if the content on the screen was larger than the view height then it should have worked fine. The only thing I could think of was conflicting js. I often have all my js in the same file but wrap them around functions that only get called on the pages that I need them to run.

Comment: Thank you very much! Wrapping the js in functions and calling it on the pages that I want them to run on worked.
Can I ask you another question? You seem experienced in using stackoverflow. I just made my account yesterday and this was my first question. Two people voted my question as not useful. This resulted in me not being able to ask questions for a short time and a warning that my account might get blocked. What should I do better next time when I ask a question?

Comment: I'm quite new to it too, but I think the main thing was that your initial question didn't have enough context for us to easily debug. (ie when I said your page doesn't have height). Your current edits to the question make it much better.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if it's that but i think you have to had that before src
or maybe wrong path

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything. Besides I have other code in the same external script file that works just fine.

Comment: ok but it should be that <script> thing because your code work or it's a problem in your file
can you add your file content ?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your javascript code in an executable function:

```
(function() {

   // your code

 })();
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't change anything